# Using LLDT and configuring the GDT for it

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, osdev

I'm working on a small OS that will use a separate Local Descriptor Table for each process.  I understand that I will need to use the `lldt` instruction to load a LDT segment from my GDT.  I already have my kernel running in protected mode with a valid GDT, but I cannot figure out what the GDT entry for my LDT should look like.  I understand that its base address should point to my LDT, but I don't know what the privilege level and other attributes should be.  Here is the NASM code that represents the LDT entry in my GDT:

```
localTable equ $-gdt            ; GDT entry #5 (selector 20h)
dw 0x1FF                        ; limit to 64 descriptors
dw 0x8000                       ; base address
db 0x0
db 0x89                         ; probably incorrect...
db 0x1f                         ; possibly incorrect...
db 0x0
```

If you are not familiar with the NASM syntax, this table entry has a base address of 0x8000 and a limit of 511 (512 bytes total, or 64 entries).  I have read the section about the GDT and LDT in the i486 programmer's reference manual, but I cannot fully understand what my GDT entry should look like.

Anyway, I load the LDT like so:

```
mov ax, 0x20
lldt ax
```

This code causes the processor to generate a general protection fault (I handle it with an interrupt).  I would like to know two things:

1) Did I correctly describe my LDT in the GDT?  If not, what needs to be changed?
2) Could the `LLDT` instruction be failing because there are invalid selectors in my LDT itself?  I read the LLDT instruction spec, and it seems to me that it doesn't even read the memory of the LDT, but I just want to be sure the LLDT isn't failing because I have a typo in my LDT's data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  The type that I was using (`1001b`) was not what I needed.  I found that type 2 (`10b`) is used for LDT entries.  For the record, this information is in chapter 6, page 4, of the *i486 Microprocessor Programmer's Manual*.  My functional GDT entry looks as follows:

```
localTable equ $-gdt            ; GDT entry #5 (selector 20h)
dw 0x1FF                        ; limit to 64 descriptors
dw 0x8000                       ; base address
db 0x0
db 0x82                         ; 10000010b (segment present set, WTM)
db 0x1f
db 0x0
```